# Slider navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make this simple slider for a project.

I have made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PEgu/6/

I need help with building my navigation so i can jump to the different slides back and fourth using the CSS class. Im not sure how to do this from this point. I need jquery to switch the class on my slider-panel-wrap with the class dependent on what button is pressed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
<div class="slider-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="slide-one">Slide red</span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="slide-two">Slide blue</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="slider-panel-wrap">
    <section class="slider-panel red-background" id="slider-panel-1">TEST SIDE 1
        <div class="slider-caption-wrap"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="slider-panel blue-background" id="slider-panel-1">TEST SIDE 2
        <div class="slider-caption-wrap"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #567;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.slider-panel-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #F50;
}
.slider-panel {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #F20;
}
.red-background {
    background-color: #F20;
}
.blue-background {
    background-color: #567;
}
.slider-wrap-0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    -o-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
.slider-wrap-100 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide-two').click(function () {
        $(".slider-panel-wrap").addClass("slider-wrap-100");
    });
});
```

thank you

Comment: Your panels have same ID.
Will your slider have only two slides, or a lot ?

Comment: its a mistake - updated version here. I basicly just need a smarter way to use the Jquery than this, if possible: http://jsfiddle.net/GARCd/1/

Beneath this fullscreen slider one just like it will come and maybe more beneath that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple method :

- Count the number of child
- hide all slides
- show the first slide and set a currentSlide var to 0
- make a slide function : pass the index as an argument. hide all slides, show the slide equivalent to the argument...

if you want a prev next function, you just have to increment or decrement the currentSlide var and pass it to the slide function.

I hope my english is understandable.

** (Update) A little implementation :**

```
var slides = $(YOURCONTAINER).children(yourslideclass);
slides.hide();
var numberOfSlides = $(YOURCONTAINER).children(yourslideclass).size()-1;
var currentSlide = 0

function changeSlide(slideID){
currentSlide.hide();
$("yourslideclass:eq(slideID)").show();
currentSlide = slideID;
}
```

For a next slide function, per exemple :

```
$(nextSlideButton).on('click',function(){
   if(currentSlide+1 <= numberOfSlides){
      changeSlide(currentSlide+1);
   }
});
```

And you can even add some nice transitions like fade or slide in show and hide functions :)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you - but im not sure how to make this, so i will prolly have to use the other method.

Comment: Sure, i will make a little copy paste from a plugin i'm currently writing. But, if you don't know of to do, and if you are doing this for work and not for learning, why don't you use a jquery plugin ? There are a lot of simple and perfect sliders.

Comment: Well its kinda learning, but i need it for my exam project, so i will need to make it as simple as possible so i can explain what i have done :) Thats why i need it very simple, light-weight and with a lot of CSS ( i use the CSS transform translateY to slide, i would like to keep using CSS for this if possible?). I cant use a big plugin with all sorts of functions i dont need and cant explain. Plan is to add a CSS timer aswell - but thats later on.

Comment: It will be very hard to do everything with CSS, maybe impossible.
Keep in mind CSS is for styling only.

Comment: Thank you, i will play with it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the thing that's wrong now is that you can't navigate back to the red slide.
Try this expanding your jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.slide-one').click(function() {
    $(".slider-panel-wrap").removeClass("slider-wrap-100");
    $(".slider-panel-wrap").addClass("slider-wrap-0");
});
$('.slide-two').click(function () {
    $(".slider-panel-wrap").removeClass("slider-wrap-0");
    $(".slider-panel-wrap").addClass("slider-wrap-100");
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/6PEgu/8/

Comment: Thank you for this fast reply - but then if i have 3 slides i get into trouble again.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/6PEgu/14/

there is not "smarter" way to do this than add classes in the jquery? so if i have maybe 10 slides, my jquery will have remove 10 classes or?

Comment: Because i will have 1 more slider beneath this one - this is basicly going to be used as a fullscreen slider and then 2-3 more like it down under - hope you understand what i meen. I will do as your example, but each of the fullscreen divs should function as a slider. so i really need a navigation for each inside the fullscreen slide.

Comment: basicly i just want the Jquery to be handled smarter than this if possible, but with the same outcome: http://jsfiddle.net/6PEgu/23/